# diplsay status data from json feed and display each result on td field of html table

Tags: javascript, php, json

hello there i am trying to display the result of data request of a json feed and put it into a html table. the json data looks like this:

```
0->data->status:RESOLVED  1->data->status:RESOLVED
```

and so on . . .

```
[{"data":{"status":"RESOLVED"}},{"data":{"status":"RESOLVED"}}]
```

I am accessing the feed using this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function livedepotrack () {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://www.xxxxx.org/livexxxx.php",
            method: "GET",
            success: function(depolivetrack) {
                //    console.log(depolivetrack)
                //  var statusdepojs = depolivetrack[key].data.status;
                //console.log(key, depolivetrack[key].data.status);
                //Object.keys(depolivetrack).forEach(function(key) {
                // var lolo = depolivetrack[key].data.status;
            //});
                var mainContainer = document.getElementById("livedepostatus");
                for (var i = 0; i < depolivetrack.length; i++) {
                    var div = document.createElement("div");
                    div.innerHTML = depolivetrack[i].data.status;
                    mainContainer.appendChild(div);
                } 
            }
    })
    
    console.log('DEPOTRACKER');
    //console.log(b);
    })
}
var interval = setInterval(function () { livedepotrack(); }, 6000);
</script>

echo "<td align='center' width='200'>   <span class='badge bg-info'><div id='livedepostatus'></div></span>           </td>";
```

inside while that runs over a sql query i have the td tags for the table  i am calling the result like this

```
 echo "<td align='center' width='200'>   
            <span class='badge bg-info'>
                <div id='livedepostatus'>
                </div>
            </span>           
        </td>";
```

Now i have seen the code working but not in the right way i creates a div element and it repats, this code is something i put together copy pasting from the web so i am bit stuck, what i need is to display the result of the json on each row of the html table and when interval functions runs it updates that field. hope you can help me thanks in advance

Comment: It's unclear what your code's output is and what you want it to be. Can you show a simplified example?

Comment: Sure, please check this images, one is the html table, the other is the json data. view https://ibb.co/wr531PX

json https://ibb.co/kB88Zw7

what i need is each of the status text value (RESOLVED) appears in each corresponding row of the table.

Comment: In that case, you're building HTML that isn't valid to begin with - all your divs have the same `id`, and those need to be unique. And how do you connect the correct table row to the value in the report?

Comment: well i am planning to use php for that